# Test Flash using Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

I'm using selenium rc and i need to test flash.  I need to click Allow button on Flash player.
I just need some help getting started?

Comment: You mean the allow button on the Flash Player settings window?

Comment: Yes, I've mean allow button on the Flash Player settings window

Comment: @oksana: I do not think you can do that with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can not do flash testing using selenium until and unless Selenium flash API is integrated to flash file with the help of flash developer.

You may check out one ready made flash file with selenium flash API integrated in the link below.

http://mayurshah.in/selenium-flash-test/

Hope this may help.

Thank you,
Mayur